# convert parameter to json in sol

Tags: json, solr

I send this to SOLR with browser

http://localhost:9063/solr/Object_Collection/select?q=*:*&facet=true&f.DateRangeValue.facet.range.start=NOW/YEAR-10YEAR&facet.range=DateRangeValue&facet.range.end=NOW
/YEAR&facet.range.gap=+1YEAR

I want to convert it to JSON

Answer (score 0):

you must end with
&wt=json

for example
select?q=*:*